# Any way to default git svn dcommit to fail if code is out of date?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, rebase, dcommit

I like how (normal) git won't let me push if I haven't rebased with the latest code.  However with git svn, when I do git svn dcommit it automatically rebases (i.e. git svn rebase) and then commits.  Is there a way I can have it throw up an error message if there is new stuff to rebase?

Comment: I believe it commits, and then rebases on top of the new SVN revision. I don't think SVN has any way to abort the commit if it's not already at the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. There is always a chance that somebody will commit right after you made any check-as-you-are-looking-for and right before you actually commit something. Just run `git svn fetch` every time before `git svn dcommit` to be almost sure git won't rebase automatically.